# Databinding to TextBlock in WP7

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, data-binding

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <Kids> 
      <Child> 
        <Name>Kid1</Name> 
        <FirstName>hisname</FirstName> 
      </Child> 
    <Child> 
        <Name>kid2</Name> 
        <FirstName>SomeName</FirstName> 
      </Child> 
    </Kids>
```

I have used Linq to XML to read my xml file.
Now I want to databind the result to a textblock in my
windows phone 7 application. 
I have a class called SerializeKidToXml. In that class I have a function called ReadXML that looks like this:

```
  public string ReadXml()
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream test = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("YourKids.xml", FileMode.Open, store))
            {

                var testxdoc = XDocument.Load(test);
                var returnval = from item in testxdoc.Descendants("Kids").Elements("Child")
                                select new
                                {
                                    kind = item.Element("FirstName").Value
                                };
                return s.Append(returnval).ToString();

            }
        }
```

Now I want the result of this query to bind with a textblock that is located
on the interface of an XAML page. I am trying to bind it by using code behind the XAML page. This is what I have now:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerializeKidToXml t = new SerializeKidToXml();
            textBlock1.Text = t.ReadXml();

        }
```

The textblock on the XAML page is not showing me the result string but instead this: 
System.LINQ.Enumerable......

Any help would be appreciated. Thx.

Comment: Sample of your UI and structure that holds the data from xml file would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you:

```
  var returnval = from item in testxdoc.Descendants("Kids").Elements("Child")
         select item.Element("FirstName").Value;

     foreach(var str in returnval)
     { 
        s.Append(", ");
        s.Append(str);
     }
     return s.ToString();
```

---

If you want to show kids in a listbox:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ReadXml()
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream test = new      IsolatedStorageFileStream("YourKids.xml", FileMode.Open, store))
            {    
                var testxdoc = XDocument.Load(test);
                var collection = from item in testxdoc.Descendants("Kids").Elements("Child")
                                select item.Element("FirstName").Value;
                return collection;

            }
        }
```

and  use it:

```
   SerializeKidToXml t = new SerializeKidToXml();
   listBox.ItemsSource = t.ReadXml();
```

Comment: thx it partially works because now the textblock shows: { kind = Johnny }. How do I remove { kind = ?

Comment: I don't have a Vusial Studio now, so try the updated code, please.

Comment: wow, thx. Is it possible of using a listbox instead of a textblock?